# Erro ao chamar um método de classe dentro do main

Tags: java

Estou tentando chamar um método no `main`, porém a classe não me permite fazer-lo.
Aparece o erro:

> "Cannot Make aStiatic References to the non-static method"

Possuo a classe `Gerenciamento`, onde o método está contido:

```
public class Gerenciamento {

public double totalCaixa;

private ArrayList<Bicicleta> bicicletas = new ArrayList<Bicicleta>();


Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);

public void cadastrarBicicleta()
{
    String cor = null, marca = null, modelo = null, acessorio = null;
    int numIdBici = (bicicletas.size());
    boolean ok = false;

    System.out.print("\n----- Cadastro de Bicicleta -----\n\nInsira cor: ");
    do {
        try {
            cor = leitor.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            ok = true;
        }
    } while (ok == true);

    System.out.print("\nInsira marca: ");
    do {
        try {
            marca = leitor.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            ok = true;
        }
    } while (ok == true);

    System.out.print("\nInsira modelo: ");
    do {
        try {
            modelo = leitor.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            ok = true;
        }
    } while (ok == true);

    System.out.print("\nInsira acessorios: ");
    do {
        try {
            acessorio = leitor.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            ok = true;
        }
    } while (ok == true);

    boolean disponivel = true;
    bicicletas.add(new Bicicleta (numIdBici,cor, marca, modelo, acessorio, disponivel));
    numIdBici = (bicicletas.size());
    System.out.println("\n##### Bicicleta criada com sucesso! #####");
}
```

E possuo o main, onde nao consigo chamar o método

```
public class TesteCicloTurismo extends Gerenciamento
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcao;
        do
        {

            switch(opcao)
            {
            case 1:
                cadastrarBicicleta();//metodo nao pode ser chamado aqui
                break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está tentando chamar um método de instância dentro do `main`, que é estático. O método só existirá quando existir uma instancia de `Gerenciamento` ou da classe `TesteCicloTurismo`.

Adaptando para seu código:

```
public class TesteCicloTurismo extends Gerenciamento
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TesteCicloTurismo teste = new TesteCicloTurismo();
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcao;
        do
        {

            switch(opcao)
            {
            case 1:
                teste.cadastrarBicicleta();//metodo nao pode ser chamado aqui
                break;
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigada!
Fiquei até com vergonha agora, de pedir algo tão fácil hah

Comment: @DacKR. Hey, não fique com vergonha. Todos nós aqui passamos por essa fase do aprendizado :)

Comment: @gabrielfalieri ?? Se foi pro OP, você pode citá-lo para que a mensagem seja direcionada a ele, colocando "@"+o nome usado por ele :)